# What maximum OpenGL context do the Macbook Pro's support on Bootcamp Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, cpu

I'm Looking to get MacBook Pro. Is there a max OpenGL context?
I understand that on OS X it is 4.1, does this change when booting in Windows, and is this diferrent or the same for the three models?

Models 2015:
13 inch integrated, 
15 inch integrated, 
15 inch with amd graphics.

Comment: It's helpful to provide as much info as possible.  For example, which model years are you referring to?

Comment: totally missed that - the current versions - 2015

Comment: Edit your question to reflect that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13 inch integrated:
Intel HD graphics - supports OpenGL 4.5

15 inch integrated 
Intel iris pro 5200 - supports OpenGL 4.3

15 inch discreet:
AMD radeon r9 m370x - supports OpenGL 4.5